# Not updating links when opening a file with xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am using xlwings to open excel files and read data, but I am being prompted to update links for every file. I don't need to update the bad links in the file, I just want them ignored. Is there a way to give xlwings a default command so I am not prompted to update the links on open?

Here is the code I am using:

```
import xlwings as xw
wbPath = [PathToWorkbook]
wb = xw.Book(wbPath)
wb.save(wbPath)
wb.close()
```

Comment: see here: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/562